# How to fix FormData.entries() not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an `<input type="file">` which I'm trying to upload to a remote server. I saw a video where this is accomplished by appending the selected file object to a `FormData` object, and sending using `http`.

The problem is that my `FormData` object is empty. I saw online that to examine `FormData`, one needs to iterate through `FormData.entries()`, but I get an error `entries is not a known property of "FormData"`. I saw an online fix involving adding:

```
declare global {
    interface FormData {
      entries(): Iterator<[USVString, USVString | Blob]>;
    }
  }
```

to my `polyfills.ts` file, and then declaring `USVString` in @types/usvstring.d.ts with `type USVString = string;` and adding `types = ["../@types/usvstring"]` into `tsconfig.app.json`. I've done all that but I still get a compile error:

```
ERROR in src/app/selection/selection.component.ts(38,25): error TS2495: Type 'Iterator<[string, string | Blob]>' is not an array type or a string type.
```

Does anyone have any idea here how to fix?

My source code is here:

```
<h1>UPLOAD PHOTO</h1>
<input type="file" (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
<button (click)="uploadFiles()">Upload</button>
```

```
  onSelectFile(event) {
     this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  uploadFiles() {
    let fd = new FormData();

    fd.append('image',this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);

    for (const entry of fd.entries()) {  // <-- ENTRIES() NOT RECOGNIZED
      console.log(entry);
    }

    this.http.post("localhost:3000/test-photo",fd)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
  }
```

Comment: That issue happens in Safari, right? That is because FormData.entries() is not supported by Safari!

Comment: I'm using Firefox. But, I thought the steps I implemented above were supposed to be a workaround?

Comment: If `entries()` is not supported, how can I examine `FormData`? It appears empty, as many others have indicated. Tks!

Comment: Oh, I didnt know it is not supported by FireFox. But I guess you are using an older version of it that might not be supported by it yet. I had a workaround in the past, if you want, I can share it with you

Comment: Yes, please! Many thanks in advance if you can please share that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, I will be sharing it my workaround for iterating through FormData.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries#Browser_compatibility) for `FormData.entries()`, it seems like it is indeed not supported by the older versions of Firefox, as it is only supported by Versions 44 and beyond. Likewise, it is not supported by Internet Explorer (IE), as well as anything before Safari 11.

So, what I did was to create a dictionary, and then manually map it over to your FormData. Therefore, if you need to iterate it for any purposes (such as debugging or anything), you iterate through the dictionary rather than the FormData itself.

```
const formDataDictionary = {
  'image': this.selectedFile,
  'image2': this.selectedFile2
};

const fd = new FormData();
for (const key in formDataDictionary) {
  fd.append(key, formDataDictionary[key]);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use ES6's spread syntax to iterate through FormData, which should work fine given Angular will do the transpiling work for you.

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image',this.selectedFile,this.selectedFile.name);
console.log(...fd);
```

Comment: Didn't test it, but I doubt Angular will be able to transpile `...fd` if `fd[Symbol.iterator]` has not been polyfilled before hand, you'll probably just have `{}`. And if `fd[Symbol.iterator]` has been polyfilled, then its `.entries()` method should be quite simple to polyfill too, since it's supposed to be the same function. And the first part of this answer doesn't help in logging what's been saved in the FormData at all.

Comment: @Kaiido you're right about that. TBH I didn't test out the 2nd method too. My idea was to manually iterate through the innumerable properties of FormData or something.. In that case, does that mean a `for..in` loop won't work for FormData too?

Comment: Yes it won't work either. Entries of a FormData are not enumerable, and used to be opaque before it became an Iterable. Though the [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get) method may have better support, so one way would be to save the keys and then call this method.

Comment: @Kaiido good point, thanks for raising that. I guess that really depends on OP's intention on iterating through the FormData itself. IMO, he should iterate through the files before it is transformed to a FormData object (and hence my first method of constructing a Dictionary), or iterate it on the server-side instead.

Comment: Many thanks, @wentjun. I tried your solution, but it's still not working (My Firefox version is 66). The post fails and I get the same console error I received previously: `ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "localhost:3000/test-photo", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for localhost:3000/test-photo: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }`. It seems the `FormData` object is still empty.